# Batch download of Microsoft patches

Tags: windows, patch-management

I have servers which require patches, and they cannot be directly connected to the Internet.

I've run a tool offline on the servers to determine exactly which security patches I need, which returns me the following:

```
KB2538242
KB2538243
KB2727727
KB2820197
KB2813430
KB890830
KB976002
KB2861855
...
```

How can I batch download these hotfixes from Microsoft directly via script? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

WSUS Offline might be able to help you, I beleive it is scriptable to some extent.
http://www.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: +1 for WSUS Offline. Probably the best bet for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Never come across the scripting of downloading patches. You would use WUSA.EXE to script the install of patches, however.

Have you not considered WSUS Server for patch deployment for your servers?

Answer (score 0):

I use BatchPatch (https://batchpatch.com/) to install patches on servers that do not have internet connectivity. It downloads patches to a directory on a server with access to the internet and then installs them on other servers using Windows' built-in updating functions.